# Distribute a transparent static library

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, static-libraries

I want to distribute a closed source C++ static library, let us call it MyLib. This library uses Boost.
What is the best way to give the ability for the developers who are going to use MyLib to link against whatever they want configuration of boost.

In other words, They may already be using a static version of Boost or a shared version of it linked to their program. So, i want to leave the option to them.

P.S. I am building my library with CMake and distributing a CMake package for it for the final developers.

Comment: Why not just distribute different builds of your library?

Comment: @ChristianHackl That what I am trying to avoid. I made the question simple. But actually I am linking against 3 libraries with different configurations

Comment: If your library links dynamically with boost then users can supply their own version.

Comment: Simply do not link your library with Boost when create it. So users may link the library with Boost at their side. [I may be wrong, but calling `target_link_libraries` for *STATIC* library shouldn't link anything: a linker isn't called when create a static library.]

Comment: As long as you keep the use of boost internal to your library (which I would recommend for a close-source distribution) it doesn't matter what version/configuration the eventual user has. It is only if you try to use boost in your public interface that you run into trouble, Particularly if the parts of boost you rely on in that public interface require dynamic boost libraries.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir thanks. I have to expose part of it to the public interface

Comment: By using particular version of boost in your static library you force users of your static library to use exactly the same version of boost with exactly the same configuration flags. Otherwise they will be thrown into the fun land of ODR violations and unreproducible bugs. If you are exposing some boost stuff as a part of interface there is no workaround at all, even making your library dynamic won't help.